# Бинарное дерево для слов из букв

Tags: python, бинарное-дерево

Нужно написать дерево, которое хранило бы в ячейках символы из слов, которые были добавлены.

Задание звучит так: Хранение и распознавания слов на основе бинарного дерева. интерфейс основного класса должен содержать методы для добавления и роспизнавання указанного слова. Каждый узел дерева представляет собой объект, содержащий определенный символ, и ссылки на две ветви Left и Right. переход по ветви Left осуществляется если текущий символ строке распознаваемого совпадает с символом хранящейся в данном узле дерева. если символы не совпали осуществляется переход по ветке Right.

вот пример

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в таком порядке слова и были добавлены.

вот ещё код, который за это отвечает: https://hastebin.com/nekivugoni.py

текущая проблема: дерево не строится должным образом. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что я делаю не так?

Comment: ну... правильность тут не в счёт. они просто должны быть такими по условию. это практическая в университете. и я пытаюсь разобраться, что я делаю не так. ну и можно сказать, что в первом примере неправильно то, что первого слова (tesa) нет - оно пере записалось почему-то. на счёт кода - просто мне казалось, что его довольно много (60 строк) и будет удобнее смотреть там. наверное, можно что-то убрать, но даже не знаю, что.

Comment: ну... я могу дать весь текст задачи. но он только породит больше вопросов. я попытался максимально упросить в меру своих возможностей. 
"вот так должно быть - а вот так по факту".
материала из учебника (как и самого учебника) нет.

Comment: может вас просят [Двоичное дерево поиска](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0) реализовать?

Comment: Хранение и распознавания слов на основе бинарного дерева. интерфейс основного класса должен содержать методы для добавления и роспизнавання указанного слова. Каждый узел дерева представляет собой объект, содержащий определенный символ, и ссылки на две ветви Left и Right. переход по ветви Left осуществляется если текущий символ строке распознаваемого совпадает с символом хранящейся в данном узле дерева. если символы не совпали осуществляется переход по ветке Right. 
вот всё задание. к сожалению, это не дерево для поиска. я уже писал деревья с цифрами. с ними проблем не возникло.

Comment: Зачем повторять один и тот же вопрос с одними и теми же ошибками в коде? left_child и right_child как были None, так навсегда и остались.

Comment: ну... не совсем. код теперь работает. проблему с созданием детей я исправил.

Comment: или у меня остались эти ошибки? можно, пожалуйста, тыкнуть в них?

Comment: Да, немного поменялась картина. Теперь левые ветки старательно пересоздаются при каждом добавлении слова. Кроме самого первого слова - у него вторая буква сворачивает направо.

Answer (score 2):

> Каждый узел дерева представляет собой объект, содержащий определенный
>   символ, и ссылки на две ветви Left и Right.

В Питоне:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Node:
    value: str
    left: 'Node' = None
    right: 'Node' = None
```

> Переход по ветви Left
>   осуществляется если текущий символ строке распознаваемого совпадает с
>   символом хранящейся в данном узле дерева. если символы не совпали
>   осуществляется переход по ветке Right.

```
def extend_node(node, chars):
    for char in chars:
        node.left = Node(char)
        node = node.left

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self, words=()):
        self.__tree = None
        for word in words:
            self.add(word)

    def add(self, word):
        if not word:
            return  # do nothing
        chars = iter(word)
        if not self.__tree:  # first word
            node = self.__tree = Node(next(chars))
            extend_node(node, chars)
        else:
            parent = node = self.__tree
            assert node
            for char in chars:
                while True:
                    if not node:
                        node = Node(char)
                        setattr(parent, child, node)
                        extend_node(node, chars)
                        break
                    elif node.value == char:
                        parent, node, child = node, node.left, 'left'
                        break
                    else:
                        parent, node, child = node, node.right, 'right'
```

Чтобы из стандартного ввода слова прочитать:

```
tree = BinaryTree(map(str.strip, sys.stdin))
tree.to_dot(sys.stdout)
```

где [`to_dot()` просто дерево в виде, понимаемом graphviz печатает](https://gist.github.com/zed/b2af40d17fec628ee82df16ba69eecbf):

```
$ echo $'tesa\nterm' | python . | dot -Tpng | display
```

[image: binary-tree-tesa-term]

Comment: `| python . |` - это не ошибка?

Comment: нет. Файл назван `__main__.py` (посмотрите по ссылке) — это позволяет текущую директорию (имя `.`) выполнить.

Comment: наверное стоит добавить этот комментарий в ответ... Я думаю немногие знают о таком способе запуска скриптов... Например я не знал

Comment: @MaxU: эта возможность в Питоне с Python 2.6 присутствует, ~лет 10.